# how can I display controller's variable (which is on a loop) on .html.erb page? ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, hash, render

I have the following code listed below in my controller:

```
struc = {'en' => 'english', 'es' => 'espaniol', 'de' => 'germany', 'fr' => 'french', 'it' => 'italy'}
struc.each_pair do |key, value|
  @key=key
  @value=value
end
```

on my application.html.erb I have the following

```
<select name="Language" onchange="location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value="/<% @key %>/<%= @rem %>"><%= @value %></option>
</select>
```

Now how can i make the value of '@key' and '@value' appear recursively display on   (application.html.erb)?

**Also How can I change its styling i.e. make the value appear smaller, tucked in nicely??**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not something like

```
in controller

@langs = { :en => 'english', 
           :es => 'espaniol', 
           :de => 'germany', 
           :fr => 'french', 
           :it => 'italy' }

in view

<select name="language" onChange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
  <% @langs.each_pair do |short, long| %>
    <option value="<%= short %>"><%= long %></option>
  <% end %>
</select>
```

Comment: genius thanks :) Fantastic, implemented it works splendidly well!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to make struc available to the view by turning it into an instance variable - ie, @struc.  Then in your view do

```
<select name="Language" onchange="location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">

<% @struc.each_pair do |key, value| %>
        <option value="/<%= key %>/<%= @rem %>"><%= value %></option>
<% end %>

</select>
```